# The Term pipenv is not recognized

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

Im trying to start up my API using a virtual environment. Only problem is pipenv is deciding to not work.
This is the error im getting.

pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pipenv --version
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I have put the directory into the path, which according to other Stack posts is the answer, but it still gives me this error when I ask anything with pip. In order to check if it worked im using $ pipenv --version

Comment: Windows ? Forget it as a developer. Go linux :)